# Using Office 365 Distribution Groups in a SharePoint column or workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, column, distribution-lists

I am creating a document template library which is going to email our users when we upload a new template (powerpoint, word, etc). I am hoping to send this email to distribution groups I've already created in Office 365 Admin center. Unfortunately I can't find a way to select distribution groups from a people picker (as it's only looking at SharePoint users/groups).

Am I crazy? I feel like this should be easy as these are distribution lists that live in Office 365's admin/exchange center.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use distribution groups.

You must convert them to Mail enabled security groups or Office groups.